# Installing Language Tool in TexStudio

Tags: texstudio, grammar

I am attempting to install `language tool` on my texstudio distribution in order to check my grammar. Currently, I am following this guide to install `Language tool`. http://wiki.languagetool.org/checking-la-tex-with-languagetool

The problem is, I cannot find `languagetool-standalone.jar` nor `LanguageToolGUI.jar` in any of the downloads at the bottom of http://languagetool.org/ . Can anyone tell me where can I locate these files?

Comment: Isn't it just the standalone desktop tool?

Comment: Supposedly. I extracted all 3 downloads and am still unable to find the files.

Comment: If it helps, I running Windows 7.

Comment: I have also left instructions for integrating LanguageTool into TexStudio [here](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=29612&p=110222#p110222)

Comment: I get an error just as Foad did, with error msg = LT current status: error. Then I changed the URL to localhost\8081/v2/check. Then LT current status: working is shown.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I am using TeXstudio with Language Tool under Windows 7 without any problems. The entry in the wiki is not valid for the newest version. You need to use the `languagetool.jar`. Then everything should work.  All the other files you mentionend, existed in previous version of the tool, but are now removed. See [the changelog.](https://github.com/languagetool-org/languagetool/blob/master/languagetool-standalone/CHANGES.txt)

Comment: Which file do I download? Also, do you know which are the exact names of the files? Because I cannot find anything about filenames being changed in the changelog (it must be too far back that it has been removed)

Comment: @WetFeet Just download the newest version as a zip, which is 2.4.1,  and then everything should be fine. Unpack the zip-file in the directory you like and start the `languagetool.jar`. The change of the file names occurred in the recent version 2.4

Comment: How do I start the `languagetool.jar`? When I double click it my computer opens it like a compressed folder.

Comment: how do I start `languagetool.jar`? When I double click it, my computer opens it like a compressed folder.

Comment: You need to install the java jre first to execute jar files.

Comment: Run the following from the command line: `java -jar languagetool.jar`

Comment: The most recent CHANGELOG is available at https://github.com/languagetool-org/languagetool/blob/master/languagetool-standalone/CHANGES.md. However, it does not show the new files.

Comment: I used `languagetool-server.jar` *LT Path* and `http://localhost:8081` in *Server URL* and it worked for me. I checked this by going to a browser and entering the link `http://localhost:8081/?text=i%20eatting%20cake&language=en`. This gives a xml as output.

Answer (score 30):

You may follow the steps as shown in the clip (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VYIY7bbSv4Q):

1. Download and install Java of 32 or 64 bits version from http://www.java.com/en/
2. Download Language tool from https://dev.languagetool.org/http-server (Old versions: https://languagetool.org/)
3. Unzip the downloaded package and open languagetool.jar. Open "Text Checking"-> "Options", tick "Run as server on port" and set it as 8081.
   [image]
4. Open Texstudio and click on "Options"->"Configure Texstudio".
   Check the "Inline Checking" in "Editor" section.
   Make sure that "Show advanced options" in the lower left corner is checked, and modify the "LanguageTool" in "Grammar" section as below.
   Specifically, set "Server URL" as "http://localhost:8081", "LT Path" and "Java" respectively as the paths of "languagetool-server.jar" (Old Version "languagetool.jar") and "java.exe".
   [image]

To test this, (re)start texstudio, and check whether the Languagetool is running on the desired port by navigating to http://localhost:8081/ on your machine.

Note that the TexStudio 2.12.6 **does not work** with Languagetools version > 3.5 since the http API is [no longer offered](https://languagetool.org/http-api/migration.php). [Fixed in a later version](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/1842/).

Comment: It's far better to include the relevant parts of what you reference...

Comment: Hi @Werner the clip is just as short as 3m; and an elaboration seems to be redundant and irreverent of the originality.

Comment: Answers here should be self-contained so there's minimal click-through to other sites for information. What would happen to the value of your answer if the YouTube video is taken down? Your answer would become completely *irrelevant*.

Comment: @Werner Sorry for my ignorance and thanks for your reminding. Details completed.

Comment: To update. In TeXstudio config, "Language check", "Server URL" must have: "http://localhost:8081/v2/check".

Comment: @djnavas  Should the server url option be localhost:8081/v2/check" or localhost:8081/" or we need to change it after checking it?

Comment: How do we use it instead of the default tool in TexStudio?

Comment: @skan I am not sure at this moment, because I no longer use LanguageTool. Its use was cumbersome and was unable to add new rules with spanish, because the implemented rules are insuficient, particularly for business reports.

Comment: very detailed installation suggestions ever. Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

The answer for Linux Users ;)

1. **Download** the [LanguageTool for desktop](https://languagetool.org/download/LanguageTool-stable.zip)
2. **Unpack** the downloaded .zip file (just provisionally) in your download folder. The terminal command is, for example, `unzip LanguageTool-stable.zip`
3. In the unpacked folder you will find the *version subfolder* `LanguageTool-5.5` (of course the exact name depends on the LanguageTool version)
4. **Move** the **version subfolder** to an appropriate directory. I personally recommend the root directory `/opt`. Therefore, write in terminal `sudo mv LanguageTool-5.5 /opt`
5. Adapt the **Settings in Texstudio** (`Options > Configure TeXstudio > Language Checking > LanguageTool`) There you introduce following: (see picture)

a. The path of the `languagetool-server.jar` file in the *LT Path* field.  In our case we type: `/opt/LanguageTool-5.5/languagetool-server.jar`

b. The path to the java platform in the *Java* field. In our case we type:  `/usr/bin/java` (of course it is prerequisite that you hava java installed)

[image]

> Thanks to @shivang-patel for providing the updated link to the application. And to @soham for giving the new name of the `.jar` file.
>
> In old versions of LanguageTool (e.g., version `4.7`) the name of the file is `languagetool.jar`

Comment: When I did your approach localhost:8081 returns: `Error: Missing arguments for LanguageTool API. Please see https://languagetool.org/http-api/swagger-ui/#/default`@loved.by.Jesus

Comment: Sorry @Alper, I have no idea what the error's cause is. I hope you have found the answer (maybe in another forum). If you find the answer, please write it down here as a comment or, better, link it. If it is relevant we can add it to my answer. ;)

Comment: How do we use it after that configuration?

Comment: @skan when you restart TexStudio, you will see that false spelled words are underlined. :)

Comment: Worked for me on TexStudio 2.12 and Languagetool 5. One point to note though... Don't download the Libreoffice version(with oxt extension)from the site. I didn't happen to find the "languagetool.jar" file inside it. As instructed in this answer download the zip file and you're good to go.

Comment: Please check this link:  https://dev.languagetool.org/http-server.html

All info available related to Language Tool.

Comment: this answer is outdated

Comment: You just need to give `languagetool-server.jar` in the LT path, instead of `languagetool.jar`. Save your 15 mins.

Answer (score 16):

This is a recent and more detailed solution for Windows users.

1. Make sure the last version of TeXstudio is downloaded from its [website](https://texstudio.org/).
2. Download the English dictionary (*.oxt) from [here](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions/english-dictionaries) to the directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\TeXstudio\dictionaries`.
3. Download languagetools (*.zip) from its [website](https://languagetool.org/) (I used `D:\Applications\LanguageTool-4.8` as its directory).
4. Navigate to LanguageTool directory, then open `languagetool.jar`. Go to `Text Checking > Options`, then check `Run as server op port` and type the port number `8081`. Click `OK` and close.

[image]

5. Open TeXstudio and go to `Options > Configure TeXstudio > Language Checking` while making sure the `Show Advanced Options` is checked.
6. Click on `Import Dictionary...` and navigate to `C:\Program Files (x86)\TeXstudio\dictionaries`, then choose the dictionary `*.oxt` you downloaded.
7. Make sure the default languae is selected (e.g. `en_US`), and the thesaurus is selected from the same directory (e.g. `th_en_US_v2.dat`).

[image]

8. Check `Start LanguageTool if not running`.
9. Set the values `Server URL`, `Java`, `LT Path` and `LT Arguments` to `http://localhost:8081/`, `java` (as recommended [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/2251/#0a85)), `<directory of LanguageTool*-*>\languagetool.jar` and `org.languagetool.server.HTTPServer -p 8081 --languagemodel --allow-origin "*"` (as recommended [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/2251/#4140)), respectively.

[image]

In order to make sure everything is fine, click on `Help > Check LanguageTool` in TeXstudio. The output should be something like this

[image]

Comment: I have problems with LT on macOS as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/538702/102825). when running the Check LanguageTool it returns `Tries to start automatically. LT current status: error`

Comment: https://languagetool.org/download/LanguageTool-stable.zip