# Problems Installing Language Tool in TexStudio

Tags: texstudio, languages, ubuntu, grammar

I'm trying to install LanguageTool in TexStudio, as described in [Installing Language Tool in TexStudio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155148/installing-language-tool-in-texstudio), but I cannot succeed.

LanguageTool server is working as can be seen from this test:

When I out this on my browser:
http://localhost:8081/v2/check?language=en&text=my+text

I receive:
{"software":{"name":"LanguageTool","version":"3.7","buildDate":"2017-03-27 10:50","apiVersion":"1","status":""},"warnings":{"incompleteResults":false},"language":{"name":"English","code":"en"},"matches":[{"message":"This sentence does not start with an uppercase letter","shortMessage":"","replacements":[{"value":"My"}],"offset":0,"length":2,"context":{"text":"my text","offset":0,"length":2},"rule":{"id":"UPPERCASE_SENTENCE_START","description":"Checks that a sentence starts with an uppercase letter","issueType":"typographical","category":{"id":"CASING","name":"Capitalization"}}}]}

But after making all this configuration on TexStudio, grammar checking doesn't work.

Does anybody has clue on how to debug it?

I'm using:
Ubuntu 16.04
TexStudio 2.10.8
LanguageTool: 3.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use language tools [version 3.5](https://languagetool.org/download/LanguageTool-3.5.zip). Configure TexStudio for v3.5 and restart it. Hopefully it will work.

Comment: Thank you rabeeh. With this version it worked very well. Today I could find the error messages displayed in terminal. The problem with LanguageTool Version 3.7 is presented: "You're using an old version of our API that's not supported anymore. Please see https://languagetool.org/http-api/migration.php".

Comment: Is this documented somewhere in TexStudio documentation?