# TeXstudio is connected to Languagetool, but does not show errors

Tags: texstudio

I've downloaded and set up [LanguageTool](http://wiki.languagetool.org/checking-la-tex-with-languagetool) to connect to TeXstudio like this:
[image: TeXstudio settings]

LanguageTool is starting when I start TeXstudio and, according to the icon, connected:
[image: LT is connected]

Additionally, I'm able to manually perform a check using my browser. For instance by opening:

```
http://localhost:8081/v2/check?text=W%C3%A4hrend%20Sie%20das%20Ganze%20mir%20einem%20Holzl%C3%B6ffel%20oder%20einem%20Paar%20St%C3%A4bchen%20r%C3%BChren.&language=auto
```

However, these problems are not shown in the TeXstudio editor itself:
[image]

According to [Finding errors using n-gram data](http://wiki.languagetool.org/finding-errors-using-n-gram-data), LT should highlight the word "mir" here. (The issue is not related to n-grams, other problems also don't show up.)

As suggested in [Problems Installing Language Tool in TexStudio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366404/problems-installing-language-tool-in-texstudio), I also tried the same thing with LT-3.5, but still face the same problem. (Errors are not highlighted)

If you do not know the answer to the problem, could you suggest steps to debug? (E.g. where to find TeXstudios log files, if there are any)

Comment: The exact same problem still persists for me. TeXStudio (2.12.14) is connected to LanguageTool (4.4); the test link you pasted works fine in the browser. In TeXStudio, no grammar errors are shown (spelling errors are). Everything seems to work in theory. I am on `en_GB`, so there should be no issues with language settings that are not valid, as in your answer. `Inline Check` of grammar is enabled.

Answer (score 3):

As it turns out, this issue is related to the **selected language**, where "de_DE_frami" is **not** a valid option. After installing another version of the German spell checking dictionary (via `sudo apt install hunspell-de-de`) and selecting it in the options, LanguageTool now highlights the errors correctly.

[image]

Comment: Had to symlink `ln -s /usr/share/hunspell/de_DE.dic de.dic`, because LanguageTool does not know `de_DE` as a Language. Also symlink the .aff file. This way i got it working.