# Software to check grammatical errors in Latex text

Tags: text, text-manipulation

Is there any software, like Grammarly, that enables one to check the grammar in the text while using latex. The problem with using Grammarly is that with formulas and mathematical notation, it becomes very tedious to use Grammarly.

Comment: Do you think this link is useful for you? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6333/grammar-checking-tool-for-use-with-latex

Comment: Probably not the answer you are looking for: I copy my text (if it's important) paragraph by paragraph in **MS Word** for this purpose. Then I copy the corrected text back into my LaTeX text editor. So far, I did not have any problems (just effort).

Comment: Related: [Installing Language Tool in TexStudio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155148)

Comment: @marmot spelling ≠ grammar