# Problem with Texstudio and Languagetool

Tags: texstudio

I use language tool on text studio. Language tool categorizes all errors as ''grammarMistake''. In fact, language tool has different categories, but texstudio interprets all of them as ''grammarMistake'' Any fix?
Here is a picture of how it looks in TexStudio(the red underline is coming from Texstudio default spelling mistake property):
[image]

Comment: Can you give an example of that? I use LanguageTool for English an Portuguese, never had such problem. Did you check this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155148/installing-language-tool-in-texstudio#155665

Comment: The question you mentioned is not relevant. I can definitely run the Languagetool and it captures all the errors it can. The problem is all of them are underlined using the same color. If you check the syntax highlighting, you can see that the language tool is using the "grammarMistake" color for all the errors it finds. I have another issue with Languagetool 4.1as well, which is 100% CPU usage on my surface pro, which needs another thread I know.
BTW, everything works perfectly on my mac but sucks on my surface.