# Install LanguageTool jar or server?

Tags: texstudio, languages

I use TexStudio and LanguageTool on Windows. I followed this tutorial
[Installing Language Tool in TexStudio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155148/installing-language-tool-in-texstudio).
I use as LT path `C:\Program Files\texstudio\LanguageTool-5.7\languagetool.jar` the Jar - file.

From time to time you can read in tutorials that they use the server file. Which is more "correct" the jar or the server file?

Answer (score 2):

The file languagetool.jar has in its GUI options the possibility of hosting a webserver:

[image]

However, it's more appropriate for a simple and direct grammar checking:

[image]

To use Language Tool in another program (e.g., TexStudio) you only need the server version (languagetool-server.jar). Call it in the command line with:

```
java -cp languagetool-server.jar org.languagetool.server.HTTPServer --port 8081 --allow-origin
```